# How to get deployment version of added existing project using c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I want to get the deployment version from another application if we pass the link of the location of the main project whose dll has this version:

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps to get the deployment version from anther app.

First, I make a winform app(named TestWinform) and a console app(named TestConole).

Second, I published the console app and set his deployment version is `1.0.0.3`.

Third, I add the project `TestConsole.application` from path `Solutionname\TestConsole\bin\Debug` into the winform app.(Adding existing project)

Fourth, I write the following code in the winform app.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"../../TestConsole.application"));
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 1)
            {
                dt = ds.Tables[1];
                MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0]["version"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Finally, I get the version.

[image]